# Some questions about spacetime topology, causality structures and other GR businesses

Tags: general-relativity, hamiltonian-formalism, topology, de-sitter-spacetime

1. What are the exact conditions required for the [canonical transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation)? Most papers just assume away with [global hyperbolicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_hyperbolic_manifold), but is there a more general condition for it?

"Quantum gravity in 2+1 dimensions" does contain an [ADM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism) description of the [2+1 D equivalent of the Kerr black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTZ_black_hole), which also contains [CTCs (Closed Time-like Curves)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve) (but no event horizon since vacuum solutions in 2+1D have a vanishing Riemann tensor). And some spacetimes with CTCs (or non-time orientable) do have a well-enough behaved Cauchy problem, so I am wondering **how far causality can be weakened until you cannot define a hamiltonian**?

2. Why is [De Sitter space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_space) always assumed to have the topology $\mathbb{R}\times S^3$? I know it cannot be $S^4$, which would be the most natural (just a Wick rotation of the sphere metric), since $S^4$ does not admit a Lorentz structure, and I guess that it cannot be $\mathbb{R}^4$ because I think it would suffer from geodesic incompleteness (missing pole and all). But why $\mathbb{R}\times S^3$, and is there any other manifold that would admit that metric? I guess that $S\times S^3$ would work, and whatever other terrible quotient manifold you could do with $S^3$.

Comment: For the second part of your question, the equation of the 4 dimensional De Sitter space could be written $-x_0^2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 x_i^2 +x_4^2 = R^2$, that is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 x_i^2 +x_4^2= x_0^2 + R^2$, so for $x_0$ fixed, the equation  clearly represents a sphere $S^3$, so we may speak of a topology $ \mathbb R \times S^3$.

Comment: Regarding the first question, what is the meaning of *canonical transformation* in this context? I do not understand well the issue on dS topology, or perhaps just its formulation. De Sitter spacetime is the maximally extended maximally symmetric solution of Einstein equation with a (given) strictly positive cosmological constant: these requirements definitely fix the manifold (topology and metric), nothing further may be "assumed". The topology turns out to be $R\times S^3$ as said by Trimok.

Comment: The first question basically relates to the ability of defining a hamiltonian on some spacetime. As for the second question, metrics are not necessarily tied to one manifold (although some manifolds may not allow particular metrics at all). "Exact solutions of Einstein's Field Equations" does define it on R^4 (although I assume they care more about local solutions than global structures). So I am wondering if there is any "well behaved" topology that may also work (SxS^3 is a bit acausal) and if there is, why that particular standard choice.

Comment: Thanks. Hamiltonian for generic fields or for the gravitational field? Because when you speak of CTCs it seems that you already know the structure of the spacetime and not that you have to compute it solving the Cauchy problem for the metric in the ADM formulation.

Comment: Well both ideally, since you can always have some (partial) Cauchy surface developping closed timelike curves at some point (or just being there from the start, cf that 2D Kerr derivation). But generic fields would be interesting as well, yes.

Comment: you are right when saying that "metrics are not necessarily tied to one manifold" since they are locally obtained, but in the case of dS one usually intend the maximally symmetric and extended solution and it fixes the topology. If I correctly understand, you are asking if a *local dS patch* can be extended into another larger manifold with a topology different from the standard one $R\times S^3$. I do not know. If you impose that the manifold (and the metric) is real analytic I suspect that the standard dS is the only maximal extension of that patch.